# string copy function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
void my_strcpy(char *sour,char *dest){
 if(sour == NULL || dest == NULL){
  return;
 }
 while(*sour != '\0'){
  *dest++ = *sour++;
 } 
 *dest = '\0';
}
int main(){
 char *d = NULL;
 char *s = "Angus Declan R";
 d = malloc(sizeof(char*));
 my_strcpy(s,d);
 printf("\n %s \n",d);
 return 0;
}
```

This func works fine and prints the string. My doubt is as the pointer "dest" will be pointing to the '\0' how does it prints the whole string(as it didnt point to the initial address of the string).

Comment: That first check should be `(sour == NULL || dest == NULL)` (OR, rather than AND).  Also, the malloc line should be `d = malloc(strlen(s)+1);` (`d` needs to point to a buffer that is large enough to hold every character in string `s` plus the NULL character)

Comment: `d = malloc(sizeof(char*));` doesn't allocate enough memory on most systems. Usually a pointer is four or eight bytes large.

Comment: Just a small suggestion, you could improve your function by having it return an int. Maybe the number of characters copied, and something to indicate if the pointers are NULL (like -1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that `dest` will point to the *end* of the string. But you are *not* printing the string by using `dest` - you are printing the string by using `d` which is a different variable.

Remember that in C and C++ values are passed by value by default - so when you call the function `my_strcpy` the value of the variable `d` is copied into the variable `dest` which is local to the function `my_strcpy` only and any changes to that variable will not affect `d`.

Also note that you are *not* allocating enough space for your `d` variable:

```
d = malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

This will allocate enough space for a *pointer to character* which will usually mean enough space for 4 (or maybe 8) characters. You should allocate enough space for the string you intend to copy *plus* one character for the terminating null byte. What is the size of the string you are trying to copy? Hint: `strlen` should help.

Answer (score 0):

The `d` pointer passed in is a copy of the pointer, so the position/movement of the pointer in your function is not reflected back to where it was called in `main`. While `d` and `dest` both point to the same block of memory (at least initially) and any changes to that block of memory will be reflected on both ends, the `dest` pointer is only a copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
 my_strcpy(s,d);
```

C passes arguments by value. The value of  `d` is passed to  `my_strcpy`, which means `d` object inside `main` is not modified in your `my_strcpy`  function.